# Reliable Software and Secure Software

Tags: linux, windows

What is the difference between reliable software and secure
software?

I am googled but i can't find answers for this question. can you help me by explaining it?

Comment: If you want help then you will need to explain context of the terms and what your problems understanding the differences are. The definitions of the words "reliable" and "secure" can be found in any dictionary and are rather  distinct concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reliable - doesn't crash

Secure - doesn't send your password to random people

Pretty much covers it.

Comment: can you explain it little more.